# How do I get google sheet conditional formatting custom formulas to refer to relative cells?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a google sheet where I want the range `A:D` to format a certain color if the contents of `A2` contain the word `Order` (case insensitive).  Right now I have the following:

- Conditional Format applies to range - `A:D`
- Format cells if... - `"Custom formula is"`
- Custom Formula - `=SEARCH("Order",$A$2)`
- The chosen background color for the formatting style

So the trouble is the formula `=SEARCH("Order",$A$2)` searches exactly cell A2 for every row.  I want every row to be relative so that row 3 searches A3, row 4 searches A4 etc etc.  How should the custom formula be written so that it's relative instead of exact?

I can't get this to work for some reason, and I have hundreds of rows so I can't just add the conditional formatting individually.  I thought that the $'s were absolute references which makes complete sense but it won't let me save the formula as `=SEARCH("Order",A2)` - it tells me it's invalid and won't save that way.

**EDIT:** So I can save the `=SEARCH("Order",A2)` formula if I change the range from A2:D2 - but now the problem is that ONLY A2 gets highlighted when I want the whole row to highlight - the A2 relative reference applied to B2, C2, D2 when I want all of those cells to only reference A2.  How do I get the ROWS to be relative and not the COLUMNS?

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$ is to "anchor" to that row/col.  If you want the column to stay static, use $A2 and the row can adjust freely.

Comment: Haha, thanks, I really should have given it 10 more minutes before posting, I just hit a wall and then made a breakthrough right before you posted the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I understand $ is an absolute reference. What I don't understand is, how do I indicate a _relative_ cell, or which cell is it relative _to_? For example, if I apply the conditional format to `(G:L)` (columns G to L), and want to format the cells if, say, column H on the previous row is blank, what row number to I put in the formula? It would be easy if I wanted to apply it to just one row—for row 5, I'd just indicate the previous row with `ISBLANK($H4)`. But I'm applying it to all the rows, and I don't know how to specify 'the previous row'. I suppose I'm asking, which row is the context?

Answer (score 40):

```
"A"&ROW()
```

Returns `A8` if you're on row `8` (regardless of column), `A9` if you're on row `9`, &c.

You can use this along with `INDIRECT()`, which takes the value of a cell given by a string.

```
INDIRECT("A"&ROW())
```

Returns the *value in* `A8` if you're on row `8`, the *value in* `A9` if you're on row 9, &c.

---

You can also use R1C1 notation to generalize this to columns as well:

```
INDIRECT( "R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN() )
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been looking everywhere for this information!

Comment: I find the way that conditional formatting works with custom formulas is quite strange. I was able to use both of the following equations to get the same result: [1] =INDIRECT("E"&ROW())<INDIRECT("E"&ROW() - 1), [2] =E2<E1, where 'apply to range' was set for the E column. While the second form works, it's super unclear how Sheets is applying the formula in a relative way.

Answer (score 6):

Phew, finally figured it out - I can change the absolute references to be row/column specific, the trouble was that $A$2 was referencing and exact cell and A2 was relative to both row and column - I wanted to use $A2 so that only row is relative, so the answer to my question is to use this formula:

=SEARCH("Order",$A2)